# Python - вывод результата в файл с новой строки

Tags: python

Как список вывести в файл столбиком

```
k = [74.33333333333333, 66.66666666666667, 42.666666666666664, 60.333333333333336, 53.333333333333336]

with open('D:\\py\\4.txt', 'w') as ouf:
    for j in k:
        ouf.write(str(j)\n)
```

Без `\n` выводит все в одну строку, дописываю `\n` и -  `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Отметьте вопрос как правильный, если он решил вашу проблему.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Делайте так:

```
ouf.write(str(j)+'\n')  # к концу выводимой строки прикрепляется символ '\n'
```

Или так (если у вас python3):

```
print(j, file=ouf)  # print по-умолчанию выводит с переводом строки
```

Comment: Помогло, сенкс.

Comment: `from __future__ import print_function` позволяет как на Питоне 2 так и 3 использовать print-функцию.

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю еще вариант с переделыванием списка поэлементно в `multiline` строку

```py
k = [74.33333333333333, 66.66666666666667, 42.666666666666664, 60.333333333333336, 53.333333333333336]

with open("bla.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(str(item) for item in k))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
print('\n',j, file=ouf)  # без '\n' по умолчанию не проходит
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос